# 'Cannot find symbol,' but I see nothing wrong

Tags: java, object, find, symbols

It can't find my Player objects, but I declared them... What will fix my error when I try to add cards to hand?

Here is relevant part of main class:

```
while (something2.equals("yes") || playercount < 2) //Add players to game
        {
            System.out.println("Would a(nother) player like to join?");
            something2 = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            if (something2.equals("yes"))
            {
                if (playercount <= 4)
                {
                    if (playercount == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("What is your name: ");
                        Player one = new Player(scan.nextLine());
                        playercount++;
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    else if (playercount == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("What is your name: ");
                        Player two = new Player(scan.nextLine());
                        playercount++;
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    else if (playercount == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("What is your name: ");
                        Player three = new Player(scan.nextLine());
                        playercount++;
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    else if (playercount == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("What is your name: ");
                        Player four = new Player(scan.nextLine());
                        playercount++;
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    else {System.out.println("Only four players are allowed.");
                          something2 = "no";}
                }
            }
            else if (playercount < 2)
            {
                System.out.println("You need at least two players...");
                System.out.println();
            }
            else something2 = "no";
        }
        //Deal cards
        if (playercount == 2)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            {
                one.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
                two.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
            }
        }
        else if (playercount == 3)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            {
                one.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
                two.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
                three.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            {
                one.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
                two.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
                three.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
                four.addCard(Card.draw(deck));
                deck = Card.getDeck();
            }
        }
    }
```

And my player class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Player
{
private static String name;
private static Card[] hand = new Card[52];
private static int handsize = 0; 

//Constructor
public Player(String n)
{
    name = n;
}

//Mutators
public static void addCard(Card c)
{
    hand[handsize] = c;
    handsize++;
}

//Accessors
public static String getName()
{
    return name;   
}
public static Card[] getHand()
{
    return hand;   
}
}
```

I appreciate any help, and I can provide more code from my classes if you need it.

Comment: Ok, we all know the problem. But what exactly are you trying to accomplish here. A simple declare them globally may not do the trick, so I won't suggest that until I know what your trying to accomplish completely with your program.

Comment: I'm trying to add cards to the hands of the Players I created, but they aren't in the scope I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every block of code delimited by curly braces `{}` defines a scope. Any named entity declared in that scope is only accessible in that scope after its declaration.

You've declared each of your `Player` variables in their own `if` block scope. They are not accessible outside of those.

Either declare them in a larger scope, for example, outside the `if` blocks or do everything you need to do with the objects inside the block.

[Here's](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm) another description of this phenomenon.